# XSLT sort case sensitive

Tags: xslt

Please look at example:

xslt:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 
      <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="name()" case-order="upper-first"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test>
    <Z>Z</Z>
    <a>a</a>
    <A>A</A>
    <B>B</B>
    <k>k</k>
</Test>
```

Result is. This is case insensitive order. How to force upper-case letters be first?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test>
    <A>A</A>
    <a>a</a>
    <B>B</B>
    <k>k</k>
    <Z>Z</Z>
</Test>
```

But, i need something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test>
    <A>A</A>
    <B>B</B>
    <Z>Z</Z>
    <a>a</a>
    <k>k</k>
</Test>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, that's how `upper-first` is designed to work: `A,a,B,b` but not `a,A,b,B`. You need to select the uppercase elements first, then the lowercase elements.

Comment: I do not want a,A,b,B.. I need A,B,a,b... can you provide more details?

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 you can use the `http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/collation/codepoint` collation, which sorts in Unicode codepoint order.

Comment: Really, changing version to 2.0 make it works! but in .net works only with xslt 1.0 =)) =((

Answer (score 0):

You may need to sort by the case in a separate `sort` instruction:

```
  <xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:sort select="translate(name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '00000000000000000000000000')" />
    <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
```

This solution might need some testing though.

Comment: This solution not work as exprected... it will work only for "one-letter" tags...

Comment: By the way, a solution that considers more than just the first character will need another `sort` line. Yup, quite an ugly solution.